Does jobscheduler have features that Workmanager doesn't have
In the android docs it is mentioned that,

In most cases, the best option for running background tasks is to use WorkManager, though in some cases it may be appropriate to use the platform JobScheduler API.

As per the docs, Workmanager uses Jobscheduler API internally for API 22+ and alarm manager + Broadcast Receiver for API 14 - 22. Is there anything that we can achieve with Job scheduler that can't be achieved with workmanager.
